# How do I access the SSLSocket used for a servlet request within the body of the doPost( method?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jsse, sslsocketfactory

I am implementing a HTTP servlet by subclassing javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and overriding the doPost method. Within the body of the doPost method, I need to access the SSLSocket object that was used to handle the request and will be used to handle the response. The servlet container is also being used as the HTTPS server. There is no web server, load balancer, TLS termination device, etc. in front of the servlet container. Clients connect directly to the servlet container using HTTPS exclusively.

How do I access the the SSLSocket object that was used to handle the request and will be used to handle the response from within the body of the doPost method?

You may be curious as to why I need to do this. I need to access channel binding information associated with the connection. Yes, I am aware that channel binding support is not currently standardized in the JSSE specification and as a result is not supported by the default Oracle-provided JSSE provider. That is why I am using the Bouncy Castle JSSE provider which does support channel binding.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1):

First, breakpoint in the doPost and drill into the variables you see on the threadstack. There is a request/response object and they will be implementation specific (tomcat, jetty, etc...)

The solution depends on these:

a) if you can reach the sslsocket by drilling into private fields of the request or response. I know you can with tomcat.

b) if you can and are willing to write code that is using reflection, and there is no security policy preventing you from calling Field.setAccessible(true) and obtaining the value with Field.get(..)

c) if you are capable of handling failures and you have a clear indication that regressions on this non-compiled code can be detected in dev or qa. This is because the server version will be updated for sure in the future and your code may suddenly break without a compilation error. Integration tests is a must.

So you probably guessed it, with reflection you can drill into any fields of the request or response.